# Biztalk Unsupported Edifact Schemas

Tags: biztalk, edi

I need to use a newer version of an edifact schema of the d12b type. This doesn't come out of the box in Biztalk 2010. I've also checked and this version is also not included in Biztalk 2013. This version was released in 2012.

Is there a place to download these schemas as I haven't been able to find it? Or is there a way to create these schemas? Any other way to use a d12b type edifact from Biztalk?

Comment: Have you tried manually editing an older version of the schema? Usually they don't change too much between versions if at all. Which message type is it?

Comment: IFTSTA. That sounds doable if there's not too much structural change. The reason I need to move to this version is because one of the segments has a bigger max occur. If I get the go ahead with this project, I'll give this a shot and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of EDIFACT schema are now only available in standard and enterprise editions of latest BizTalk Servers.

```
[Installation Drive]\BizTalk Server\MSI\Program Files\XSD_Schema\EDI\MicrosoftEdiXSDTemplates.exe
```

latest EDIFACT for this message type is now D08B